# SQL: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric data type to numeric

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[_TEST]
AS
    SELECT
        a.[PS],
        b.[A0001],
        CAST(a.[Area] AS DECIMAL(15, 10)) AS A0002,
        CAST((b.[0001] / a.[Area]) AS DECIMAL(15, 10)) AS A0003
    FROM
        dbo.Areas AS a
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 
             LEFT(PSOA, 6) AS PS, SUM([0001]) as A0001
         FROM 
             dbo.Counts
         GROUP BY 
             LEFT(PSOA, 6) AS b ON a.PS = b.PS
```

The view creates fine but I get the error below when using it:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric data type to numeric

Now, from my understanding, that means the values are too big to fit into a `Decimal(15,10)`. However, manually calculating them, the biggest value I get for `A0003` is `2151.93382`, which is fine for a `Decimal(15,10)`. I even tried `Decimal(20,10)` just to be sure and that returns the same error. The figures are definitely not too big, so what's going wrong?

Comment: `However, manually calculating them` ... don't manually calculate anything.  Do a `SELECT MAX(value)` from your table and see what the largest value actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This is not giving the error and that error might be due to some other reason. Check with your other data which can be bigger than this.

```
Select Cast(2151.93382 as Decimal(15,10))
```

You can check the demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/NZJN96582).

How many rows are there in the table I think `SUM([0001])` can produce a big number in resulting arithmetic overflow exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the max Area value was actually a Decimal(16,10) which explains this. Not sure how I missed that!